# Getting properties using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm using reflection for getting some properties, and I'm having problems getting one when the `GetValue(item,null)` returns an object.
I did:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
   item.GetType().GetProperty("Site").GetValue(item,null)
}
```

Doing that, I got an object `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Site`. Debugging it, I can see all properties of that object, but I can't get it. For example, one property is: `siteName`, how can I get the value of that?

Comment: Why the `null` parameter? Wouldn't [GetValue(object o)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx) overload be better?

Comment: As for getting the value: you can make another reflection call on returned object or just use the [`dynamic` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) to do the job for you.

Comment: i`m trying with another reflection but i can`t get it..

Comment: some more code with the second call would be appreciated.

Comment: i don`t have it.. i was trying but i couldn`t make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamicProxies generated by Entity Framework are descendants of your POCO classes. That is, you actually can access all properties if you upcast the result to POCO:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
   YourNamespace.Site site = (YourNamespace.Site)item.GetType().GetProperty("Site").GetValue(item,null);
   Console.WriteLine(site.SiteName);
}
```

If you need to use reflection for some reason, this is also possible:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    PropertyInfo piSite = item.GetType().GetProperty("Site");
    object site = piSite.GetValue(item,null);
    PropertyInfo piSiteName = site.GetType().GetProperty("SiteName");
    object siteName = piSiteName.GetValue(site, null);
    Console.WriteLine(siteName);
}
```

Reflection is slow, so I would use TypeDescriptor if I do not know the Type in compile time:

```
PropertyDescriptor siteProperty = null;
PropertyDescriptor siteNameProperty = null;
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (siteProperty == null) {
     PropertyDescriptorCollection itemProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(item);
        siteProperty = itemProperties["Site"];
    }
    object site = siteProperty.GetValue(item);
    if (siteNameProperty == null) {
     PropertyDescriptorCollection siteProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(site);
        siteNameProperty = siteProperties["SiteName"];
    }
    object siteName = siteNameProperty.GetValue(site);
    Console.WriteLine(siteName);
}
```